# Modify h1 inside a tsx file using a javascript function in js file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to generate random prompts inside of a H1 element in my tsx file. I have looked for solutions regarding this and all of them point to doing this in my index.html file, but I do not have one of those and I don't think I need one for the app I am making.

Here is the code I have,
Javascript file:

```
export function NewPrompt() {
var prompts = [
    "one",
    "2",
    "three"
]
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.Length);
var theText = document.getElementById('PromptDisplay').innerHTML;
return(
 theText = randomNumber
);
}
```

here is the tsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonCardHeader, IonCard, IonCardContent } from '@ionic/react';
import './RandomPrompts';
import './Tab2.css';
import AddItem from '../AddItem';
import ItemList from '../ItemList';
import { mic } from 'ionicons/icons';
import { NewPrompt } from './RandomPrompts';
import { analytics } from 'firebase';
const Tab2: React.FC = () => {

  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(null);

      const getEmpty = () => {
        return ({
      title: '',
      content: '',
      date: '',
      location:'',
      clear: '',
      initialValue: ''
    });


  }

  var random = require('./RandomPrompts.js');
  const GetRandPrompt = () => {
    return ({
      random: NewPrompt()
    })
  }

  return (

<IonPage>
  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle>Writer's Unblock</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>

  <IonContent>
    <IonCard>
    <IonCardHeader>
      <div id="PromptHolder">
        <h1>Prompt: </h1>

          <h2 id="PromptDisplay" onLoad={GetRandPrompt}></h2>
      </div>
      <br />
      <h3>New Entry:</h3>
      <AddItem title={current} clear={() =>setCurrent(getEmpty())}/>
    </IonCardHeader>
    <IonCardContent>

    </IonCardContent>
    {}
    </IonCard>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>

  );
};

export default Tab2;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get no errors. I am also 100% new to ionic and react, and as my professor has not told us how to do anything I fear I am on my own to ask you guys for help. Anything you can offer would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You could start small, first try your function by itself, then try importing it in an otherwise empty ts file, add react to it, add ionic, add icons, add firebase etc. Start small and perform tests between every change, to confirm exactly which changes led to which result. You can do it! :) (As for the code: There are too many moving parts for me to read it, along the same lines: read the "minimal" section from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which is helpful advice for anyone)

Answer (score 0):

this is not the EXACT code, but it should send you in the right direction

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");

useEffects(()=>{
  let prompts = ["one", "2",  "three" ]
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.Length);
  setPrompt(prompts[randomNumber])
})

// in template
<h2 id="PromptDisplay">{prompt}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code, I see you have your NewPromt imported into tsk. Again you call it with require in var random and set NewPromt to it in getRandPromt. I don't know why you have used it. What I suggest is to import the new promt like this

```
import NewPromt from './RandomPromt.js'
```

and use it like

```
<h2 id='PromtDisplay'><NewPromt/></h2>
```

Check the actual file names and spellings. On cellular device, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. Trick was to put it in my AddItem file that adds the items to the data base.